# Preserve Autoincrement ID

Tags: mysql, database-design, auto-increment

I am working on an e-commerce webapp and here's what I am thinking about.

To make it simple in this question, the `user` table contains two columns:`id` (int,PK,NN,AI),`name`(varchar(45),NN). I want the employees have shorter ids, so I want to preserve short ids and assign them later. The id is divided in three categories.

1. 1-1000 preserved for employees.
2. 1001-5000 preserved for partners.
3. 5001+ for users.

So is there a way I can manipulate the autoincrement id? My currently walkthrough is: fires create garbage records to fill up the ID, then allocate them for employers,partners.

Comment: What will be done in 20 years when this system — which may still be used — needs to support the 1001st employee? People come and go, after all. Same with partners. Would another column that specifies whether a `user` records is an employee, partner, or regular user not work? 

Comment: If you are using MariaDB-10.3+ I's suggest using [Sequences (`NOCACHE`)](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sequences/), and one for each employees, partners and users and not use auto-increment (or skip users, and still use AI like Bill Karwin's answer and keep sequences for employees, partners).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the AUTO_INCREMENT value you would have to make the next query:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE user AUTO_INCREMENT=next_id;
```

Where you would have to replace next_id with the value that is going to be set when you omit the id in the next insert statement.

Yet the property AUTO_INCREMENT value doesn't work like you want, at least not alone, you would have to search each time which is the next value you are looking, doing a sql query in the 3 cases you said.

For example, for the case you are looking for an employee next id, you would have to make the next query:

```
mysql> SELECT MAX(id) AS max_given_id FROM user WHERE id >= 1 AND id < 1000;
```

And then do a plus 1 to that value to get the id you are setting in your INSERT with out using AUTO_INCREMENT property, or make the first given statement to alter the table AUTO_INCREMENT value and then omit the id in the insert.

One approach to do this is by doing the procedure I just explained with stored procedures:

```
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql>
mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertUserByType;
    -> /*first we try to erase the procedure if it is set, so we dont redeclare*/
    ->
    -> CREATE PROCEDURE InsertUserByType(IN pname VARCHAR(45), IN type VARCHAR(45))
    -> BEGIN
    ->
    ->     /*this is the declaration of the variable where we are storing the next value to set in the insert*/
    ->     DECLARE next_id INT DEFAULT 0;
    ->
    ->     /*we do the first case where we are inserting an employee*/
    ->     IF (type = 'employe') THEN
    ->         /*we look for the max value in the range for the given case*/
    ->         SELECT MAX(id) INTO next_id FROM user WHERE id >= 1 AND id < 1000;
    ->         IF (next_id IS NULL) THEN
    ->             /*if the max value doesnt exists we set it to the first value for this case*/
    ->             SET next_id = 1;
    ->         ELSE
    ->             SET next_id = next_id + 1;
    ->         END IF;
    ->     ELSE
    ->         /*we do the second case where we are inserting a partner*/
    ->         IF (type = 'partner') THEN
    ->             /*we look for the max value in the range for the given case*/
    ->             SELECT MAX(id) INTO next_id FROM user WHERE id >= 1001 AND id < 5000;
    ->             IF (next_id IS NULL) THEN
    ->                 /*if the max value doesnt exists we set it to the first value for this case*/
    ->                 SET next_id = 1001;
    ->             ELSE
    ->                 SET next_id = next_id + 1;
    ->             END IF;
    ->         ELSE
    ->             /*we do the third case where we are inserting an user*/
    ->             IF (type = 'user') THEN
    ->                 /*we look for the max value in the range for the given case*/
    ->                 SELECT MAX(id) INTO next_id FROM user WHERE id >= 5001;
    ->                 IF (next_id IS NULL) THEN
    ->                     /*if the max value doesnt exists we set it to the first value for this case*/
    ->                     SET next_id = 5001;
    ->                 ELSE
    ->                     SET next_id = next_id + 1;
    ->                 END IF;
    ->             END IF;
    ->         END IF;
    ->     END IF;
    ->
    ->     /*we make our insert with the recolected value and the name of the user given as a param*/
    ->     INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (next_id, pname);
    ->
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
mysql>
```

And every time you want to insert a user then write the next statement:

```
mysql> CALL InsertUserByType("User Name", "partner");
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can advance the "highest" value for the table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE user AUTO_INCREMENT=5000;
```

After you do that, the id value generated for the next insert will be 5001 or greater. The auto-increment will never generate a value lower than the current maximum of the table.

You can override the auto-increment and insert any value lower than the maximum. Just specify the value in your INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO user (id, name, ...) VALUES (478, 'Sam', ...);
```

When you do this, it's your responsibility to ensure that value isn't currently in use, and it's your responsibility to ensure that two concurrent sessions don't accidentally try to use the same id value.

The auto-increment only keeps track of a single highest value in the table, and always generates a greater number. It's guaranteed to be unique, and it works well if you have concurrent sessions doing inserts. But it's not guaranteed to give consecutive numbers (that is, it may generate a value equal to the greatest value plus 2 or more). Also it doesn't generate values within multiple ranges like you describe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want unique numbers and don't care about the actual, numerical values of same, then use an auto-incremented field.
If you *do care* about the numeric values themselves, then use a *regular* field and do the heavy lifting work yourself.

Having said that, I think you're building yourself into a corner here.

What wrong with a single, auto-increment User-Id field for everyone, *plus* a User-Type field?

```
select * 
from users 
order by type, id; 

+------+------+--------------------+
| id   | type | name               | 
+------+------+--------------------+
|  123 | E    | Fred               |
| 2345 | E    | Barney             | 
| 7890 | E    | "Mudsy" Muddlemore | 
| 3456 | P    | Snagletooth        | 
| 4567 | U    | Brenda             | 
| 5678 | U    | Dee Dee            | 
| 6789 | U    | Taffy              | 
+------+------+--------------------+
```

Remember, you are unlikely to [ever] delete a User record.
They *will* build up *over time* so, in the above example, "Barney" has `id > 1000`, but it *still* an Employee.

Comment: Not to mention if one of the long-time users gets hired so they become an employee. You'd have to change their id, and also change the id value in any other table where their user id is referenced.